# Built in function for searching sorted array in C

Tags: c, sorting, search

Is there a built in function in C for searching an integer array that has been sorted?

I can easily implement it but it seems like such a common thing - would be weird if there is no library/built in C function.

Answer (score 2):

`stdlib.h` actually contains some sorting and searching functions. `qsort` will let you sort an array in place, and `bsearch` will perform binary search on a sorted array for you. You do have to provide a comparison function in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is `bsearch()` for binary search in sorted array https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_bsearch.htm

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int cmp_int(const void *pa, const void *pb) { 
    int a = *(int *)pa; 
    int b = *(int *)pb; 
    return (a > b) - (a < b); 
}

int values[] = { 5, 20, 29, 32, 63 };

int main () {
    int *item;
    int key = 32;

    /* using bsearch() to find value 32 in the array */
    item = (int*) bsearch (&key, values, 5, sizeof (int), cmpfunc);
    if( item != NULL ) {
        printf("Found item = %d\n", *item);
    } else {
        printf("Item = %d could not be found\n", *item);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

**UPD**
Added proper comparer by @jonathan-leffler

Comment: This solution will work for "ordinary" integer values, but be careful: it may have undefined behavior when the subtraction leads to integer overflow.

Comment: @paddy just copy paste example. Feel free to provide proper comparer function.

Comment: A proper integer comparator avoids overflow by a mechanism such as: `int cmp_int(const void *pa, const void *pb) { int a = *(int *)pa; int b = *(int *)pb; return (a > b) - (a < b); }` which returns +1 if `a` is greater than `b`, -1 if it is less, and 0 if they're equal.

Answer (score 0):

you need [bsearch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bsearch.3.html#EXAMPLE), this link will take you to the manual and an example provided in that manual. alternatively in a linux box you can type

```
man -a bsearch
```